# Unpacking elements from iterable yields SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, variable-assignment

I am trying the following in Python 2.7.6:

```
a = (1,2,3,4,5)
item, *rem = a
```

and get

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It obviously works in Python 3.

How can I imitate this behaviour in Python 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is new in Python 3, so yes, it'll give a syntax error in Python 2.

For your simple single element case, you could use explicit slicing instead:

```
item, rem = a[0], a[1:]
```

For more complex setups with multiple assignments, you can put names in a tuple to unpack sub-sequences, but you'd still slice. So

```
item1, item2, *middle, item3 = sequence
```

becomes

```
(item1, item2), middle, item3 = sequence[:2], sequence[2:-1], sequence[-1]
```

This does, of course, require that the right-hand-side object can be sliced; convert an iterable to a sequence first with `list()` first to meet that requirement.